# ARM System freeze when under moderate network activity

Tags: networking, arm, ubuntu-12.04

I have an ARM system that runs Ubuntu 12.04, more specifically the Kayla development kit from SECO. This question is identical to the one posted on AskUbuntu [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/408274/system-freeze-when-under-moderate-network-activity-12-04-arm-system/).

My problem is that the system freezes when I send ethernet data to the system in the amount >60 Mb/s. Now, the system has a 1Gbit/s NIC, so the amount should not be a problem at all. The data is sent as 1KB packets at a frequency that gives the desired bit-rate. Wireshark has been used to verify that the outgoing traffic is evenly spaced in time and of the desired size and rate.

I don't need programs open, and when I stop the data traffic, the system recovers just fine. Sometimes.... sometimes... the system can handle higher data amounts; especially if it has been "warmed up".

The issue persists even when connected directly to my laptop (which I use to send the test data).

Anyone has an idea to what is going on?

Thanks in advance

Henrik

Update:
  I have tried changing MTU size, interrupt coalescing (ethtool -C eth1 rx-usecs $N), where I have had N from 3 to 1000, and also disabled checksumming. The CPU is now set to performance, as this helps some. The cpu appears less taxed when using bigger packets at the same data rate, but I still get freezes in the system.

Comment: Profile with perf. NIC might be capable of 1ghz but that might be higher load for core.

Comment: Hi, when I loaded the system with 60 Mb/s the CPU was not taxed much above idle. It is capable of dynamically changing the frequency, which was sitting around 475MHz. Are there any different metrics I should be looking for?

Comment: If scaling the cpu helps the problem (like switching to performance governor), try also to look into io_is_busy if using ondemand governor under /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/ondemand.

Comment: Two questions: 1) what kernel version are you using? 2) does the behaviour change if passing maxcpus=1 on kernel command line?

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions. I don't have access to the system before tomorrow. I'll try both there and find out what kernel version I have. Cheers

Comment: Hello Again. The kernel I use is 3-1-10 carma (specific for the ARM cpu I'm using). Forcing the governor to performance alleviates the problem somewhat, i.e. I can now fairly successfully read >100 Mb/s, but it periodically crashes at 200 Mb/s and freezes above this. I can't figure out how to pass kernel command lines. It does not have grub, and I can't find the solution on the web.

Comment: To pass the kernel parameters you will need to enter the bootloader and edit the appropriate env variables. According to some links I found on the internet, it seems that U-Boot is used on these dev kits. To enter the U-Boot you would normally just press any key (i.e. ENTER) during the early stage of booting.

Comment: Hi, got into the boot loader. 'maxcpus=1' does not seem to do anything, as per https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/528663/how-to-modify-the-default-linux-kernel-boot-options-/ . I tried the isolcpus=1,2,3 as it would be similar to having only 1 though. No change.

Comment: Couple of more ideas ... NIC driver could be possibly buggy. Maybe you could try to google if anyone experienced similar problems with this chip and/or device driver. Also see if the MTU is of the same size on both sides. If not then you could try to set the MTU size alike and see what happens then.

Comment: Hi Adi, I tried lookint at the MTU (1500 default value) and changed it around a bit. It did not change anything. Regarding driver and chip, SECO (vendor) does not list it as anything but Gigabit Ethernet, so it is probably not a well-known one. Also, looking into the drivers only show usb-ethernet drivers. Not any Gb ehternet drivers. I don't know if this is because it is an Arm system, and thus a bit different. Maybe I'm simply looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Update on that: Looking for eth1 in dmesg gave me that the ethernet card is an Intel PRO/1000, using an e1000e driver. I found a post with a guy at MIT having >100k packets/s, so I don't know if this adds any useful information.

Comment: You can find information about the ethernet PHY chip (on Seco board) by simply looking for a some kind of an identification number on the chip itself. After you get it, try to google it and I'm sure you will find it. I am not sure if I understood you well, but regarding the MTU size, this size should be set on *both* machines to the *same* size. Not sure if you've really done this ... Usually this is not really necessary but it could give an indication what went wrong in the system.

Comment: I had some of the hardware dev. guys look at my dev. board, and they could not find the PHY. The only larger ICs are USB controllers/power units or unknown. E.g. YL518E does not show anything on google.

Comment: And yes, the MTU was the same for both systems. 1500 default. Cheers

Comment: There *must* be a chip which adapts the signals from MAC (located inside the app processor) to appropriate form (i.e. voltage level) which is to be sent on wire. This kind of chip is usually called a PHY and/or transceiver. I've been googling a bit about these QSeven modules that are used on Seco platforms, and it seems that most revisions of those modules utilize PHY from Micrel: KSZ9021RNI. For some revisions, I've stumbled upon PHY's from Microchip: LAN8720A. However, you should definitely be able to find yours on your setup (most probably on SoM, and not on the carrier board). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the info Adi. SECO has informed me they'll ask nVidia's technicians for assistance, so my main hope is with them, as I'm not sure how to move forward from where I am now. Maybe someone with better insight into Linux and drivers could. Thanks to everyone who posted here!

Comment: Hello All. I just heard from SECO that they identified the bug and patched it for their normal BSP. However, they are waiting on nVidia for a compatibility issue with the Kayla board, but at least there is light at the end of the tunnel. Thanks again for all the suggestions.